# Database replication. 2 servers, Master database and the 2nd is read-only

Tags: sql-server, replication

Say you have 2 database servers, one database is the 'master' database where all write operations are performed, it is treated as the 'real/original' database.  The other server's database is to be a mirror copy of the master database (slave?), which will be used for read only operations for a certain part of the application.

How do you go about setting up a slave database that mirrors the data on the master database?  From what I understand, the slave/readonly database is to use the master db's transaction log file to mirror the data correct?
What options do I have in terms of how often the slave db mirrors the data? (real time/every x minutes?).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you want is called Transactional Replication in SQL Server 2005.  It will replicate changes in near real time as the publisher (i.e. "master") database is updated.

[Here is a pretty good walk through of how to set it up.](http://blogs.techrepublic.com/howdoi/?p=123)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 has three different modes of replication.

- [Transactional](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151706.aspx) for one way read only replication
- Merge for two way replication
- Snapshot

Answer (score 2):

> From what I understand, the slave/readonly database is to use the master db's transaction log file to mirror the data correct?
>   What options do I have in terms of how often the slave db mirrors the data? (real time/every x minutes?).

This sounds like you're talking about log shipping instead of replication. For what you're planning on doing though I'd agree with [Jeremy McCollum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1436/jeremy-mccollum) and say do transactional replication. If you're going to do log shipping when the database is restored every x minutes the database won't be available.

Here's a good walkthrough of the difference between the two. Sad to say you have to sign up for an account to read it though. =/ http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Replication/logshippingvsreplication/1399/

Comment: Just hit the link you provided and it does not look like you need an account anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this will vary depending on the database server you are using to do this.

Edit: Sorry, maybe i need to learn to look at the tags and not just the question - i can see you tagged this as sqlserver.

Answer (score 0):

Transactional replication is real time.

If you do not have any updates to be done on your database , what you need is just retrieving of data say once a day : then use snapshot replication instead of transactional replication. In snapshot replication, changes will replicate when and as defined by the user say once in 24 hrs.