# How would I implement separate databases for reading and writing operations?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, architecture, normalization

I am interested in implementing an architecture that has two databases one for read operations and the other for writes. I have never implemented something like this and have always built single database, highly normalised systems so I am not quite sure where to begin. I have a few parts to this question. 
**1. What would be a good resource to find out more about this architecture?**
**2. Is it just a question of replicating between two identical schemas, or would your schemas differ depending on the operations, would normalisation vary too?**
**3. How do you insure that data written to one database is immediately available for reading from the second?**

Any further help, tips, resources would be appreciated. Thanks.

**EDIT**
After some research I have found this article which I found very informative for those interested..

http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/

I found this highscalability [article](http://highscalability.com/plentyoffish-architecture) very informative

Comment: I'm very curious as to why. Don't get me wrong, I'm not suggesting this is a bad idea, but I've never heard of such a design pattern, and I'm very curious as to why this would be a good pattern to implement.  (Of course, I realize this may be a common design pattern that I've just never ran across before.)

Comment: Are you thinking more like one database for normal usage, and one that's read-only for reporting purposes?  Because that's a more common scenario.  Having a database for write-only access has almost no viable use cases.

Comment: If the databases are synchronized, I'm not sure how they are separate databases.  You may want to read about something like file system journaling.

Comment: Its an architecture that I have seen mentioned on sites like http://highscalability.com but no details are explained. My understanding of it is that its used to improve performance, but this is part of my questions I suppose, when would the technique be used?

Comment: What is the database platform you plan to use?

Comment: @David @Agent @WhirlWind I think that the *read/write master and read-only slaves databases* pattern is more common than you think.

Comment: @David Stratton @Agent_9191 @WhirlWind @Pascal Thivent ~ I think he intends to do something like Command Query Separation ~ Is this right @Matt ? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'm not a specialist but the **read/write master database and read-only slaves** pattern is a "common" pattern, especially for big applications doing mostly read accesses or data warehouses:

- it allows to scale (you add more read-only slaves if required)
- it allows to tune the databases differently (for either efficient reads or efficient writes)

> What would be a good resource to find out more about this architecture?

There are good resources available on the Internet. For example:

- [Highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com/) has good examples (e.g. [Wikimedia architecture](http://highscalability.com/wikimedia-architecture), the [master-slave](http://highscalability.com/blog/category/master-slave) category,...)
- [Handling Data in Mega Scale Systems](http://www.slideshare.net/directi/handling-data-in-mega-scale-systems) (starting from slide 29)
- [MySQL Scale-Out approach for better performance and scalability as a key factor for Wikipedia’s growth](http://uni-svishtov.academia.edu/AsenBozhikov/Papers/82526/MySQL-Scale-Out-approach-for-better-performance-and-scalability-as-a-key-factor-for-Wikipedia%E2%80%99s-growth)
- [Chapter 24. High Availability and Load Balancing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/high-availability.html) in PostgreSQL documentation
- [Chapter 16. Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/replication.html) in MySQL documentation
- http://www.google.com/search?q=read%2Fwrite+master+database+and+read-only+slaves

> Is it just a question of replicating between two identical schemas, or would your schemas differ depending on the operations, would normalisation vary too?

I'm not sure - I'm eager to read answers from experts - but I think the schemas are identical in traditional replication scenari (the tuning may be different though). Maybe people are doing more exotic things but I wonder if they rely on database replication in that case, it sounds more like "real-time ETL".

> How do you insure that data written to one database is immediately available for reading from the second?

I guess you would need *synchronous replication* for that (which is of course slower than asynchronous). While some databases do support this mode, not all do AFAIK. But have a look at [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/58829/how-to-keep-multiple-read-write-db-servers-in-sync) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946/database-replication-2-servers-master-database-and-the-2nd-is-read-only) for SQL Server.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent ~ Wouldn't this be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation

Comment: @drachenstern: I'm not sure CQS implies anything about the way you store data. But thanks, it's a very interesting link.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent ~ I was thinking more about the reference of having a pub/sub sync arch between the two. I was also thinking that article had images when I blind linked to it: http://www.udidahan.com/2008/08/11/command-query-separation-and-soa/

Comment: @drachenstern: Ah, yes, didn't check that link and I'm going to read that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Pascal Thivent ~ Well I could always be wrong you know, might not be what he intends ... May be totally off base. Something I'm considering how to navigate ours to atm, but I don't think our databases are well suited for this.

Comment: @drachenstern: I went through the second link and I see the "relation" but think that there is no equivalence (you can do CQS with a single database, CQS is IMHO more a pure OOP principle). Interesting read though.

Answer (score 3):

You might look up data warehouses.
These serve as 'normalized for reporting' type databases, while you can keep a normalized OLTP style instance for the data maintenance.

I don't think the idea of 'immediate' equivalence will be a reality. There will be some delay while the new data and changes are migrated in to the other system. The schedule and scope will be your big decisions here.

Comment: +1. Matt - look up OLTP and OLAP. Use one database to support fast transactional work (such as to support an app), and ETL data as required to a another database built to be reported off. As they are separate you don't get performance hits on one affecting the other.

Moving data between the databases is a complex issue on it's own - depending on how much data there is to move, and how often; when people say they want "real-time" replication between sources what do they actually mean (you need to verify) because real-time to a computer is much faster than 'real-time' to a human.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to questions 2:

It really depends on what you are trying to achieve by having two databases.  If it is for performance reasons (which i suspect it may be) i would suggest  you look into denormalizing the read-only database as needed for performance.  If performance isn't an issue then I wouldn't mess with the read-only schema.

I've worked on similar systems where there would be a read/write database that was only lightly used by administrative users.  That database would then be replicated to the read only database during a nightly process.

Question 3:
How immediate are we talking here?  Less than a second? 10 seconds? Minutes?