# Partial data transfer between two databases

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, replication

I have a SQL Server database with multiple tables. Most of them contain data that usually doesn't change.

One table (let's call it `readings_table`) contains a lot of rows and it updated all the time.

This particular table may have hundreds of gigabytes in it, while all the other tables combined might have a few megabytes at most.

Now, I have two SQL Servers deployed: one in an operational network and the other in a public network.

There is only one way communication (physical barrier) between the two networks.

I have an automatic mechanism to transfer data from one `readins_table` to another online.

What I would like to do is to set up a work process that can help me take the entire data from `DB1` (operational) except the `readings_table` table, back it up and than restore it to `DB2`.

I have read about partial DB backups, but I'm not sure if that will work in my case.

Would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: SQL Server **backup** is always all or nothing; you cannot backup *everything except one table*. Since those other tables don't contain a lot of data, I would suggest you look into creating SQL scripts that would insert that data into the database table on `DB2` (in SSMS, go to `Tasks > Generate Scripts` and then script out just the data portion of your tables in question

Comment: Why wouldn't you use SQL Replication system for this? It is working almost instantly.

Comment: @Nidzaaaa , I don't think I can replicate if the communication is one way

Comment: @marc_s , thanks, that's what I thought. So what are my options? writing a monster script that will save and restore data from all tables but the one?

Comment: If you go to `Tasks > Generate Scripts`, you can pick which tables to script out

Comment: Actually you can do One-Way Replication: check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946/database-replication-2-servers-master-database-and-the-2nd-is-read-only)

Comment: Yes, by default Snapshot and Transactional Replication is one-way/uni-directional.  I would recommend using Snapshot Replication if the data changes infrequently and if you only need periodic refreshes of the data at DB2.  I would recommend Transactional Replication if you require a near real-time copy of the data at DB2.

Comment: Also, both Snapshot and Transactional Replication allows you to replicate only a portion of the data if only a subset is needed on DB2.

Comment: From what I read , transactional replication and snapshot will not work with a physical barrier (where even simple tcp connection can't exist.) As for generate script, I do not need to copy the structure of the database, only its data, I didn't see auto-generated script to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One (very crude) way of doing this is to actually move the readings_table into a separate db all by itself.  Then you can link this table into the operational db via a SQL view (called readings_table).  This way, backups of the operational db will not include this table.

The SQL of the view in the operational db would look something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM MyOtherDB.dbo.readings_table
```

Obviously, there are lot of pitfalls with this approach, but it will work.